# adb.exe android gives me error with su

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, root-access

I rooted my device (lenovo 2107a) and then updated new custom firmware with below instructions:

- Downloaded new firmware into `sdcard/clockworkmod`
- booted to CWM
- selected "backup and restore" -> "advanced restore from internal
  sdcard"
- and chose my custom ROM
- Then i selected "system restore"

So i saw an error that said cannot restore and restore goes to break. now when boot my device i see a screen that wants to select country code and after select device will reboot again and i see same screen.

so i decided to restore my old backup, but even old backup restoring gives me the error that cannot restore.

i find the problem, when i open shell with this command:

```
adb.exe shell
$su
su
segmentation fault
```

the problem is that all of data in `/system` is read-only and i cannot even root with su. i tried everything like re-rooting device, but still i cannot shell as root.

`mount` cannot be run (operation not permitted)

`adb.exe remount` (cannot be execute)

`fixsu.sh` cannot be executed because has not access to /system (everything is read-only)

`psneuter` gives (failed to set prot mask (inappropriate `ioctl` for device))

is there any way to delete `/system` and re-upload that or something that can solve my problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly... You tried to install a custom ROM, but instead of choosing "Install from zip...", you choose "Advanced restore..."...?

Comment: yes i did, your right

Comment: did you tried `adb root` then `adb shell`?

Answer (score 0):

I got a tip from XDA dev's under Android-General Developing: give the custom ROM a new name by renaming "update.zip" on the SD Card. Under CWM, pick this "update.zip" under Update setting.

This was tested with Moto Defy+ 2.3.6 stock ROM and HTC One V GSM with a Sense 5.0 custom ROM when I tried to install MIUI 5.

Comment: Perhaps a link to that particular thread would be nice